# mod_wsgi does not recognise __init__.py

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a problem trying to deploy a simple flask app with apache2. The site structure is the following:

```
flaskapp/
├── assets
├── conf.d
├── config
    └── __init__.py # Where the configuration is
├── deploy
├── modulos
├── requirements
├── templates
└── vistas
```

Whenever I try to load the page, I get the following error:

```
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.875240 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690] mod_wsgi (pid=20674): Target WSGI script '/var/www/flaskapp/application.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.875565 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690] mod_wsgi (pid=20674): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flaskapp/application.wsgi'.
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.875723 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.875886 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/application.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.876195 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]     import vistas
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.876358 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/vistas/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.876811 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]     from .index import blueprint as inicio
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.876959 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/vistas/index.py", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.877477 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]     from modulos import api
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.877623 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/modulos/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.877965 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690]     from config import conf
[Mon Oct 05 18:40:27.878137 2015] [:error] [pid 20674:tid 140375715673856] [remote 10.0.2.2:10690] ImportError: cannot import name conf
```

And doing some debugging I've noticed the following. When I import the config in my virtual machine:

```
>>> import config
>>> config
<module 'config' from '/var/www/flaskapp/config'>
```

And when I do it in my local machine:

```
>>> import config
>>> config
<module 'config' from '/etc/flaskapp/config/__init__.py'>
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's my apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testapp.com
    ServerAlias flask.local

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp display-name=www-data user=www-data \
        group=www-data processes=1 threads=5 \
        home=/var/www/flaskapp \
        python-path=/var/www/flaskapp:/opt/env_flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup flasskapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/application.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Update: Here's an exceprt of the `__init__.py` which shows where it fails

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, yaml, datetime, locale
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cache import Cache
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_mail import Mail
from hashids import Hashids

archivo = open('/opt/carrito/conf.d/config.yaml', 'r')

conf = yaml.load(archivo)

STATIC_DIR = '%s/%s' % (conf['dirs']['full_path'],
                        conf['dirs']['static_dir'])
TEMPLATE_DIR = '%s/%s' % (conf['dirs']['full_path'],
                          conf['dirs']['template_dir'])

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=STATIC_DIR,
                      template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR)
```

Comment: What does your `__init__.py` file contain? It seems that `conf` is missing

Comment: @sirfz `__init__.py` contains the `conf` variable. I'll update the post with it.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to import from `config` in a file that's not relative to it (i.e. `modulos/__init__.py` -- perhaps there's `config.py` within `modulos/`?). You should import from `flaskapp.config` instead.

Comment: @sirfz Now I get `ImportError: No module named flaskapp.config`

Comment: You'll need to add `__init__.py` in the `flaskapp` root dir and include `/var/www/` in the `python-path` attribute of `WSGIDaemonProcess`